# How to center a custom button that has no width programmaticaly

Tags: swift, uibutton

In a collectionviewCell, I have a "MainButton" button (subclass of UIButton) :

```
var buttonTest: MainButton {
        let testBtn = MainButton(type: .custom)
        testBtn.setTitle("Save settings", for: .normal)
        testBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return testBtn
    }
```

Further, in my setup function, I introduce a basic UIView that will hold my button.

```
let supportTest = UIView()
        supportTest.backgroundColor = .blue
        supportTest.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        supportTest.clipsToBounds = true
        addSubview(supportTest)
        supportTest.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor)
        supportTest.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separator.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        supportTest.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Then i add as subview my button

```
supportTest.addSubview(buttonTest)
```

But when I constraint to center it, these 2 next lines make it crash.

```
buttonTest.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor)
buttonTest.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: supportTest.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Is there a way to properly make this button centered without giving it a width ? Because my button title will fit differently, depending its content.
I thought about a stackview, with 2 "empty" views to border it...

Tell me what you think of it.

This is how it looks like actually (2 last lines as comments of course):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s514o.jpg

Comment: By the way, this is what I get in my console : 
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600002627040 "MyApp.MainToolBarButton:0x7fcde3d56700'Save settings'.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600002626540 "MyApp.SettingsUpdateCell:0x7fcde3d54560.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.

But it works with other elements as textfields or labels

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
lazy var buttonTest: MainButton = {
    let testBtn = MainButton(type: .custom)
    testBtn.setTitle("Save settings", for: .normal)
    testBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return testBtn
}()
```

as it currently a computed property so , the instance you add to the `supportTest` is different than the 1 you set constraints to , and the latter has no superview , hence the crash

Also you set leading , trailing and centerX constraints to the button , you need a y constraint ( top / bottom / centerY )

Comment: As i introduce my buttonTest in a collectionviewcell class, I've got an error :
lazy' must not be used on a computed property

Comment: I also added Y constraint, but it crashes... as for top, I have a 20px constraint based on another element. I don't think I need a bottom one, as I give a fixed height

Comment: add subviews to `contentView`

Comment: I tried with multiple subviews, stackviews... multiple constraints... still stuck on the left side.

Comment: The only thing that works was to add (again) a subview with a fixed width centered inside the first UIView :
let insider = UIView()
        insider.backgroundColor = .yellow
        insider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        insider.clipsToBounds = true
        supportTest.addSubview(insider)
        
        insider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        insider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 168).isActive = true
        insider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: supportTest.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: But no issue without giving a fixed width....
https://imgur.com/XEbyHnt